# how to correct return value after the split String value in java?

Tags: java, android, string, methods

I received String with values = 1.0.0
but, when the String value split my String[] is [] without value!!

```
String vS = getValue();
String[] str = vS.trim().split(".");
```

but in Debug mode vS value is :  1, .0, .0
dont know why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `split()` method consumes a regex and `.` is a regex matching **any character**. Change it to :

```
String[] str = vS.trim().split("[.]");
```